# Placing red and black colors on $2 \times 4$ chessboards

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, permutation-cycles

> Suppose that two chessboards are also considered equivalent (aside from
> rotational symmetry) if one can be obtained from the other by complementing
> red and black colors. How many different $2 × 4$ chessboards are there?

The given answer is $\frac{1}{4}(2^8+2^4+0+2^4)$ , but i did not understand the zero in the parentheses. I thought that the expression must have been $\frac{1}{4}(2^8+2^4+2^4+2^4)$ such that $2^8$ came from identity permutation , $2^4$'s came from $180$ degree rotation , vertical and horizontal flippings.

Can you explain the answer given by the book , and say why my answer is wrong ?

Comment: Because "adult style hard question" has nothing to do with the question content.

Comment: @coffeemath :))

Comment: @coffeemath See the edit history. It was a superfluous description in the original title.

Comment: I don't really understand what this question is asking about, we are putting pieces onto a chessboard or something but it's not very clear what the conditions are.

Answer (score 0):

The four relevant symmetries are identity, rotation (by $180^\circ$), complementing colours and complement plus rotation. You already know that the number of boards invariant under the first two symmetries are $2^8$ and $2^4$ respectively.

There are no boards invariant under complement alone, hence the $0$. There are $2^4$ boards invariant under complement plus rotation: the top row of squares may be freely chosen, and this determines the bottom row as the complemented rotation of the top. This then leads to the final answer through Burnside's lemma.

Comment: I am not familiar with your teminology in second paragraph. I guess you are saying horizontal flipping (drawing a harizontal line which divide $2x4$ board into two $1x4$ pieces) when you said "plus rotation". However , what did you mean by "square swapping" ? Do you mean dividing $2x4$ board into $2x2$ squares using a vertical line ? Can yo please explain them clearly ?

Comment: Are you there ?

Comment: Wont you explain ? why didnt we take vertical flipping into account while taking horizontal flipping?